# power series convergence interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series

this is an MCQ question

which of the following is true

1. any power series converges on the non-empty open interval $]c-R,c+R[$
2. any power series converges on the interval $\{x:|x-c|<R\}$

where $R$ is radius of convergence and $c$ it's center as usual.

I think that they are the same answer.

i also think that the answer have something to do with the non-empty condition in the first choice but i can't prove it :"(

Comment: If $R=0$ then the interval in 1. is not open and the interval in 2. doesn't exist.

Comment: @B.Goddard
does that mean that both answers are wrong ?
and if R=0 doesn't this mean that 2. is just empty($/phi$)

Comment: My opinion is that both answers have flaws.  And yes, the second set is empty.   If you consider the empty set to be an interval, maybe 2. is correct.

Comment: ok 
thx for helping <3

Comment: I think you're right after all.  The interval in 1.  will be empty if $R=0,$ so describing it at "non-empty" is incorrect.